# run serve -s build from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, admin, startup-folder

I want to execute serve -s build from .bat file as admin, this is my .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF  
cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Brabender\build-20220517T114506Z-001"  
serve -s build
```

It works if I manually run it as admin, but I need it to run from Windows Startup Folder everytime the system starts, any ideas how to do it as admin automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor changes to your batch file, adding `/d` to the `cd` command

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Brabender\build-20220517T114506Z-001"  
serve -s build
```

Assuming we call the file something like `serve-build-script.bat`, run from `cmd.exe`

```
schtasks /create /tn "Serve-Build" /tr "c:\<Path-to-Batch-file>\batchfile-name.bat" /sc onstart /ru "user" /rp "password" /np /f
```

The correct version updated as per confirmation from the chat.

Comment: Hi Gerard, thanks for your reply. I followed your instrucions, an scheduled task has been created but it is not running, when I start the system it reminds in state "Ready"  in the Task Scheduler. Other tasks that I have created in the same way are running (example: run java -jar in a .bat file)

Comment: Is there anyway to run it on startup without human interaction when system starts or reboots from an update? wihout starting session?

Comment: Yes that is the requirement, I need to run every startup without starting he session, but it is not working... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247807/discussion-between-anna-and-gerhard).

Comment: For those looking for the right answer, this worked for me:  schtasks /create /tn "Serve-Build" /tr "c:\<Path-to-Batch-file>\batchfile-name.bat" /sc onstart /ru "username" /rp "password" /np /f

Comment: I have updated the answer with that option, @Anna. Thank you